# Getting error 'wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'DISP_EMP_DETAILS' while calling a stored procedure in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

The requirement is that I have to give the employee number and fetch the email and salary of that particular employee. Below is the PL/SQL code

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p (
    iempno    IN   NUMBER , 
    outemail  out  varchar2 , 
    outsalary out number
) IS
    lv_count NUMBER(10);
 BEGIN
    SELECT count(*) into lv_count 
    from hr.employees
    WHERE employee_id = iempno;

    IF lv_count = 0
    then
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'Employee_id ' ||iempno||' does not exist');
    ELSE
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'Select email, salary from t where empid = '||iempno||' ' into outemail, outsalary;
        dbms_output.put_line( ' Employee '||iempno||' has email: '||outemail||' and salary '||outsalary||' ');
    END IF;
END;
/
```

I am executing using exec DISP_EMP_DETAILS(198);

Comment: first of all, OUT type arguments are missing. And you should return the result of the query followed by `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`, `INTO` some variables.

Comment: Why do you exactly want the `OUT` variables in the procedure ?

Comment: @RobertoHernandez Because I want to assign the retrieved values into the OUT parameters.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan How can I give OUT arguments since I have to retrieve out parameters values. Can you show me with an example

Comment: What do you intend to do with the results - it will affect how and where variables are defined to hold the OUT results. And why are you using dynamic SQL, or querying separately to see if the ID exists (and then not filtering on the ID when you get the email/salary)? You also shouldn't rely on dbms_output to report errors - someone calling this may not have that enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this, as you don't need any `out` parameter.

Let me show you a demo

**Test Data**

```
SQL> create table t ( empid number , email varchar2(100) , salary number) ;

Table created.

SQL> insert into t values ( 1 , 'a@gmail.com' , 1000 ) ;

1 row created.

SQL>  insert into t values ( 2, 'b@gmail.com' , 2000 ) ;

1 row created.

SQL> commit ;

SQL> desc t
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 EMPID                                              NUMBER
 EMAIL                                              VARCHAR2(100)
 SALARY                                             NUMBER

SQL>
```

Now, let's simplify your code

**Procedure**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p (
    iempno   IN   NUMBER
) IS
    lv_count NUMBER(10);
    semail   t.email%type;
    ssalary  t.salary%type;
BEGIN
    SELECT count(*) into lv_count 
    from t
    WHERE empid = iempno;

    IF lv_count = 0
    then
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'Employee_id ' ||iempno||' does not exist');
    ELSE
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'Select email, salary from t where empid = '||iempno||' ' into semail, ssalary;
        dbms_output.put_line( ' Employee '||iempno||' has email: '||semail||' and salary '||ssalary||' ');
    END IF;
END;
/
```

**Testing**

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> exec p ( iempno => 1 ) ;
Employee 1 has email: a@gmail.com and salary 1000

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec p ( iempno => 3 ) ;
BEGIN p ( iempno => 3 ) ; END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20001: Employee_id 3 does not exist
ORA-06512: at "TEST1.P", line 14
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

**Summary**

- You don't need in this case out parameters, as you only want to show values.
- When you use `execute immediate` of a select, the output has to go somewhere, therefore I put two variables to get the output.
- But you have to filter the select to give you the record you want, by the employee that you know it exists.
- I use `raise_application_error` because it fits better your scenario. If the employee_id does not exist, you can exit the execution in that moment. `exception` variables are used for controlling different types of errors that you can manage later on in the exception block, applying logic over them, etc.

**UPDATE**

If you insist in using out parameters

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p (
    iempno    IN   NUMBER , 
    outemail  out  varchar2 , 
    outsalary out number
) IS
    lv_count NUMBER(10);
 BEGIN
    SELECT count(*) into lv_count 
    from t
    WHERE empid = iempno;

    IF lv_count = 0
    then
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'Employee_id ' ||iempno||' does not exist');
    ELSE
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'Select email, salary from t where empid = '||iempno||' ' into outemail, outsalary;
        dbms_output.put_line( ' Employee '||iempno||' has email: '||outemail||' and salary '||outsalary||' ');
    END IF;
END;
/
```

Run

```
SQL> declare
  2  amount number;
  3  email varchar2(100);
  4  begin
  5  p ( iempno => 1 , outemail => email , outsalary => amount );
  6  end;
  7  /
Employee 1 has email: a@gmail.com and salary 1000

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

In your case

```
set serveroutput on 
declare
 amount number;
 email varchar2(100);
begin
 <<procedure_owner>>.<<procedure_name>> ( iempno => 198, outemail => email, outsalary => amount );
end;
/
```

Comment: I totally agree .Here is the question Create a procedure named DISP_EMP_DETAILS with 3 parameters out of which one 
[ie. iEmpNo ] is an “IN” mode and other two are [ie. sEmail and sSalary] “OUT” mode 
parameters. The procedure should retrieve the EMail and Salary for the 
specified employee number in the table named “Employee” and assign 
the retrieved values to the “OUT” mode parameters. 
i. It should display an appropriate error message if the specified emp
no does not exist in “Employe” table.

Comment: I updated the answer to cover the scenario where you want out parameters. If the answer is ok, I'd really appreciate if you can accept it

Comment: Hernandez. Thanks for this. But when I am executing using exec p(198) it is giving errors like wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'P'

Comment: put the code you are using and the error in the original question.

Comment: Done. Please suggest

Comment: @Vinaykumarsingh, you can't call the procedure like that. It has to be in a declare section with the output parameters as well. Check my answer on  how I call my procedure in a block section with two parameters as  output for the procedure

Comment: ok Robert but if I want to use bind variables then what I have to do

Comment: @RobertHernandez : declare
   amount number;
    email varchar2(100);
   begin
  exec  p ( iempno => 1 , outemail => email , outsalary => amount );
    end;
  7  /
Also, this is not working for me throwing an error like PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "P" when expecting one of the following . I am using Oracle SQL developer

Comment: becasue p is not the procedure name. you have to use your own program names, what I show you was an example

Comment: As per my code, my procedure name is P only also I have edited the original question.

Comment: who is the owner of the procedure `p` ? which user are you using to connect to the database?. Your post has errors, it should be `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'Select email, salary from hr.employees where employee_id = '||iempno||' ' into outemail, outsalary;`

Comment: @Vinaykumarsingh, can you accept the answer, it is the best way to say "thank you"